# Whats the threshold to move code execution to a background thread?

Tags: android, background-task

Whats the threshold to move code execution to a background thread (asynctask, services, threads etcc) in Android ?

Say if we know a task will complete in 50 milliseconds, should we offload it to background ?

What is the limit ?

Comment: I think a simple scenario is FrameDrops situation, when you see in logcat that main thread is taking too much process then you will have to move to background task.

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation [Keep your app responsive](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr#Reinforcing) says:

> Generally, 100 to 200ms is the threshold beyond which users will
>   perceive slowness in an application.

But it also depends on what you are doing on the screen. The screen is refresh at 60Hz (16.6ms), which can be a problem if you are playing an animation.

They also gives many advices to fix this issues on the [ANR Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr)

Comment: This is indeed a precise answer.Thanks @Xiome.